# UpdatePanel not working for simple Button

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following markup:

```
<Asp:updatepanel id="up" runat="server">
 <contenttemplate>
  <asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" text="test" />
 </contenttemplate>
</Asp:updatepanel>
```

However, this is forcing a full postback.

I've created this test because a more complicated UpdatePanel wasn't re-rendering without posting back, but this simple test doesn't work as it should do either.

I've also tried declaring triggers, even though I don't believe you have to:

```
<Asp:updatepanel id="up" runat="server">
<contenttemplate>
 <asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" text="test" />
</contenttemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />        
</Triggers>
</Asp:updatepanel>
```

However, this is also not working.

Comment: Check ScriptManager's `EnablePartialRendering` property.

Comment: Cheers @YuriyRozhovetskiy, you're spot on, I don't know when that was changed. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ScriptManager's `EnablePartialRendering` and remove it if it presented or set it to `true`